# TDI V 7.1.1: how to update local jvm

Tags: java, jvm, tdi

I'm responsible for maintaining a TDI V 7.1.1 installation at a customer's site. TDI itself was installed over 4 years ago by someone else, so I don't know exactly how the installation was done back then; I just see the results.
I need to install the latest fixpack 9 in the near future; in preparation of this I found an [IBM support page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/712883) recommending to also update the JVM used by TDI.

On the customer's server I find that TDI is using the jvm installed locally below

> \TDI\V7.1.1\jvm\jre

There's no independant JVM / JRE installed on that machine. Calling

```
.\java -version
```

I found that this JVM is V 1.6.0. Now, the above mentioned IBM support page is telling me that [Java 6 is no longer supported](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/571657). Near the bottom of that page is another link talking about Java 7 or Java 8, but that only leads me back to another generic FixCentral search page.

Question is:

how can I upgrade just that local JRE from Java 6 to whatever is suitable (preferably Java 8)?

Foot note: if you feel that this question does not belong to stackOverflow please feel free to direct me to a more suitable stackExchange community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself; after 10+ attempts to place a download request at IBM's "FixCentral" site I finally managed to get to the [suitable IBM page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/720-iss-sdi-la0019) linking to the download package (7.2.0-ISS-SDI-LA0019) from FixCentral; oh dear, this is really a mess...
The package contains a README giving exact instructions on how to update.
So, for everyone interested the answer to my question is:

- yes, we can update if we have IBM's modified JRE package
- be sure to study the README esp. the part dealing with java.policy modifications